# Como selecionar um item de select automaticamente no React

Tags: javascript, react

Estou desenvolvendo um cadastro de vendas usando React e Node. Tenho um botão "Editar" onde chamo uma função que recebe uma venda já cadastrada e preenche os campos para a edição, os campos "Horas Vendidas" e "Valor Vendido" já está sendo preenchido. O select "Projeto" não está selecionado de acordo com o projeto de vendas pois ele vêm de um array próprio porque no select deve conter todos os projetos da tabela projetos.

Resumindo não estou usando nenhuma biblioteca de formulários e gostaria de selecionar um item do select ao clicar no botão "Editar". Se eu estou fazendo alguma coisa errada me digam pois eu sou novo com React. Obrigado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: poste o código por favor!

Comment: está bem complicado saber em qual momento todo o problema acontece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não está adicionando a propriedade "value" no select.

`value={projectId)`

Comment: Deu certo muito obrigado amigo!

Answer (score 0):

https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag

```
<select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
```